# Why in spring return ModelAndView prompting to download .json of view name?

Tags: json, spring, spring-mvc, spring-batch, spring-batch-admin

I have written a controller to navigate to a page named accessDenied.jsp.
I am using Spring 4.3.6 version

```
@Controller
public class BatchAccessDeniedController {

static String ERRORPAGE = "accessDenied";

public static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(BatchAccessDeniedController.class);

@RequestMapping(value = "/accessDenied" , method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView accessDenied(Principal user, ModelAndView modelAndView) {

    //Log the user who tried to access the restricted resource
    if (user != null) {
        LOG.info(user.getName() + " you do not have permission to access this page!");
    } else {
        LOG.info("You do not have permission to access this page!");
    }
    modelAndView.setViewName(ERRORPAGE);
    return modelAndView;
}
}
```

Everything works fine with the above code until I introduce Spring Batch Admin dependency and the batch admin configuration in web.xml as bellow

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        classpath:/root-context.xml,
        classpath*:/org/springframework/batch/admin/web/resources/webapp-config.xml,
        classpath:/config/spring-ldap-servlet.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Filter for Spring Security LDAP -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter>
    <filter-name>shallowEtagHeaderFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.ShallowEtagHeaderFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter>
    <filter-name>hiddenHttpMethodFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>shallowEtagHeaderFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>hiddenHttpMethodFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>runlauncher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            classpath:/config/application-web-context.xml,
            classpath*:/org/springframework/batch/admin/web/resources/servlet-config.xml
        </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>runlauncher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping> 

<!-- Invalidate user session after 15 minutes of inactivity -->
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>15</session-timeout>
</session-config>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Batch admin dependency is as below

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-batch-admin-manager</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.batch.admin}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-batch-admin-resources</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.batch.admin}</version>
    </dependency>
```

By adding this, thought the control come to the BatchAccessDeniedController Class, it will prompt to download index.json file. I am not understanding why it is asking to download index.json file rather than redirecting to accessDenied.jsp page. Also I do have configuration for spring-ldap in which index.jsp is the default page after user login.

I suspect something wrong with batch admin UI which is causing the issue. If someone has faced this similar issue, please help me getting rid of this.

Here is the link for snapshot of the download icon displayed.
[index.json file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/exQ9b.png)

Answer (score 1):

Finally after lot of research found the fix. The runlauncher servlet configured is having two servlet xml files.

1. classpath*:/org/springframework/batch/admin/web/resources/servlet-config.xml
2. classpath:/config/application-web-context.xml,

The first xml file is from the spring-batch-admin-domain jar and second xml file is the file configured in application level

Spring batch admin UI is internally having JSONViewResolver configured inside spring-batch-admin-manager.jar. Since JSONViewResolver is taking the precendence over the InternalResouceViewResolver configured in application-web-context.xml, using ModelAndVeiw was prompting to download .json of the view name returned in ModelAndView

This issue I resolved by creating two separate servlets for each xml configuration files and having different mapping as below

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>runlauncher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            classpath:/config/application-web-context.xml
        </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Batch Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            classpath*:/org/springframework/batch/admin/web/resources/servlet-config.xml
        </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>runlauncher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/batch/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping> 

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Batch Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

SO having two servlets with one servlet used for spring batch admin UI with url mapping as "/" will intercept all the incoming request with "/" followed by the mapping. Another servlet will intercept all the matching requests "/batch/*.

In this way the requests come for batch servlet uses JSONViewResolver and requests with "/batch/*" configured for application-web-context.xml uses InternalResourceViewResolver. This solved my problem.